An ellipse $\mathcal{E}$ touches a fixed ellipse $\mathcal{C}$ at $A$, prove the length of semi-major axis of $\mathcal{E}$ is constant
$\mathcal{C}$ is an ellipse with center $O$ and semi-major axis length $=a$, semi-minor axis length $|OB|=b$.
$A$ is a point moving on $\mathcal{C}$.

$E$ is a point on $\mathcal{C}$ such that $OE$ is parallel to the tangent of $\mathcal{C}$ at $A$.
$k>0$ is a constant.
$M$ is a point such that $AM\parallel BO$ and $|AM|=k\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$.
$D$ is a point such that $\vec{DM}=k\vec{EO}$.
Then there is a unique ellipse $\mathcal{E}$ through $A,D$ and tangent to $\mathcal{C}$ at $A$.
The question is: the length of semi-major axis of $\mathcal{E}$ is $ka$.

The circle centered at $M$ of constant radius $ka$ is always tangent to $\cal E$ when $A$ is moving on $\cal C$:


Dilating $\mathcal{E},D,M$ by factor $k^{-1}$ from $A$, then $\mathcal{E}$ remains tangent to $\mathcal{C}$ at $A$, so we may assume $k=1$.
Let $\mathcal{C}:x^2 / a^2 + y^2 / b^2 = 1$, $B=(0,b)$.
Let $A=(a\cos(\alpha),b\sin(\alpha))$, $\alpha\in\Bbb R$. Then $E=(a\cos(\alpha+\frac\pi2),b\sin(\alpha+\frac\pi2))$.
$A-M=(0, \sqrt{a^2 - b^2})$
$D-M = k (E-O)=(a\cos(\alpha+\frac\pi2),b\sin(\alpha+\frac\pi2))=(-a\sin(\alpha),b\cos(\alpha))$
So the ellipse $\mathcal{E}$ is the curve $t\mapsto M+\cos(t)\vec{MA}+\sin(t)\vec{MD}$ with parameter $t\in[0,2\pi]$

How to show the semi-major axis length of $\mathcal{E}$ equals $ka=a$ [independent of $\alpha$]?

The following is one way to do it (but I expect there is better method).
To find the maximum of a point on $\cal E$ to its center $M$,
$$=\|\mathbf{M}\pmatrix{\cos(t)\\\sin(t)}\|$$
where $\mathbf{M}=\pmatrix{x_A-x_M&x_D-x_M\\y_A-y_M&y_D-y_M}=\pmatrix{0&-a\sin(\alpha)\\\sqrt{a^2-b^2}&b\cos(\alpha)}$
The matrix $\mathbf{M}$ is not symmetric.
Calculate $\mathbf{M}^T\mathbf{M}$ (WA computation)
$$\pmatrix{0&-a\sin(\alpha)\\\sqrt{a^2-b^2}&b\cos(\alpha)}^T\pmatrix{0&-a\sin(\alpha)\\\sqrt{a^2-b^2}&b\cos(\alpha)}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a^2-b^2 & b \sqrt{a^2-b^2} \cos (\alpha) \\
b \sqrt{a^2-b^2} \cos (\alpha) & a^2 \sin ^2(\alpha)+b^2 \cos ^2(\alpha)
\end{array}\right)$$
Two eigenvalues of $\mathbf M^T\mathbf M$ are (WA computation)
\begin{aligned}
& \lambda_1=a^2 \\
& \lambda_2=\left(a^2-b^2\right)\sin^2 (\alpha)
\end{aligned}
Clearly $\lambda_1>\lambda_2$.
So the maximum of a point on $\cal E$ to its center $M$ is $\sqrt{\lambda_1}=a$ (we also get the minimum is $\sqrt{\lambda_2}$).
So the semi-major axis length of $\mathcal{E}$ is $a$.
